# Is DT Register interested by new Paypal IPN IPs?

Tags: paypal, joomla

I have a Joomla site (3.8.10) with DT Register 3.3.2; we are using the Paypal plugin for payment and all is working fine.

Today I received an email from Paypal saying they are increasing  their structure and that they added some IPs used to send IPN notification;

I would need to know if DT Register filters in some way the IPs from which it receives IPN so that I must add in some way the new IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the developers of DT Register, not Stack Overflow.

Checking hardcoded IP addresses is a bad practice, domains should be used for filtering, and postback verification of all IPNs.

It's unlikely such a plugin engages in that bad practice itself.